# shiny + ggvis: reactive using ggvis "tilde" or "~"

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

All I want is an efficient way to set the ggvis `fill` property in `server.R` according to the InputSelect box in `ui.R`. Since the `fill` property syntax needs a "**tilde**" or "**~**" I was unable to come with a solution.

The `ui.R` and `server.R` below are just one of my solutions attempts: **my switch statement below is wrong** since I get a "`Error in switch(select, mpg = { : EXPR must be a length 1 vector`". Don't hesitate to propose something completely different.

Thanks in advance for your support !

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("select", label = h3("Select box"), 
                  choices = list("mpg" = "mpg", "hp" = "hp", "cyl" = "cyl"), 
                  selected = "mpg")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("ggvis_ui"),
      ggvisOutput("ggvis")
    )
  )
))
```

server.R

```
data(mtcars)

shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {
    select <- reactive({as.character(input$select)})
      data <- switch(select, 
                     mpg = {mtcars %>% 
                       ggvis(~mpg, ~wt, 
                             fill = ~mpg) %>% 
                       layer_points() %>%
                       bind_shiny("ggvis", "ggvis_ui")},
                     hp = {mtcars %>% 
                       ggvis(~mpg, ~wt, 
                             fill = ~hp) %>% 
                       layer_points() %>%
                       bind_shiny("ggvis", "ggvis_ui")},
                     cyl = {mtcars %>% 
                       ggvis(~mpg, ~wt, 
                             fill = ~cyl) %>% 
                       layer_points() %>%
                       bind_shiny("ggvis", "ggvis_ui")}
      )    
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to running the `select` expression using `select()`, and wrap your switch in an `observer` to plot the data reactively:

The `server.R` would be:

```
shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {
    select <- reactive({as.character(input$select)})
    observe({
    data <- switch(select(), 
                   mpg = {mtcars %>% 
                            ggvis(~mpg, ~wt, 
                                  fill = ~mpg) %>% 
                            layer_points() %>%
                            bind_shiny("ggvis", "ggvis_ui")},
                   hp = {mtcars %>% 
                           ggvis(~mpg, ~wt, 
                                 fill = ~hp) %>% 
                           layer_points() %>%
                           bind_shiny("ggvis", "ggvis_ui")},
                   cyl = {mtcars %>% 
                            ggvis(~mpg, ~wt, 
                                  fill = ~cyl) %>% 
                            layer_points() %>%
                            bind_shiny("ggvis", "ggvis_ui")}
    ) 
    data
    })
  }
)
```