# How to initialise default values for rendered items in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

**Introduction**

In a `shinyApp`, I would like to render output with dynamic input.

My problem is, using `shinydashboard` with different tabs, that default values from `*Input()`s only get rendered when the respective tab is activated (think of an input and an output tab).

I get the same behaviour, when using a `switch` statement on `input$*` values in a simple example (unless after rendering the input, the `switch` does work and output appears). See the following:

**Code**

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(uiOutput("select_bin")),
                                       mainPanel( plotOutput("distPlot"))))),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$select_bin <- renderUI({
      selectInput("bins", "Number of bins:", c("few", "many"))
    })
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      x    <- faithful[, 2]
      bins <- switch(input$bins, few = 10L, many = 100L)
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = bins)
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
  })
```

The code above works, but throws a

`Warning: Error in switch: EXPR must be a length 1 vector`.

I suppose that `input$bins` is not available until the `selectInput` is rendered.

**Question**

How can I define a default value for `input$bins`, so before the `selectInput` is rendered, the expression in `renderPlot` does not throw the warning?

**First approach**

I tried to use `observe` as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28876873/shiny-ggvis-reactive-using-ggvis-tilde-or), but I am not sure of it's exact meaning, and thus struggle to solve the problem.

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(uiOutput("select_bin")),
                                       mainPanel( plotOutput("distPlot"))))),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$select_bin <- renderUI({
      selectInput("bins", "Number of bins:", c("few", "many"))
    })
    observe({
      bins <- switch(input$bins, few = 10L, many = 100L)
      bins
    })
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      x    <- faithful[, 2]
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = bins)
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
  })
```

Which does not work at all and throws the additional `Warning: Error in seq.default: object 'bins' not found`.

Answer (score 2):

Using

- `reactiveValues` to create a list of defaults, and
- `observeEvent` for the `input$bins`, updating the defaults

seems to solve the problem:

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(uiOutput("select_bin")),
                                       mainPanel( plotOutput("distPlot"))))),
  server = function(input, output) {
    values <- reactiveValues(bins = 10L)
    output$select_bin <- renderUI({
      selectInput("bins", "Number of bins:", c("few", "many"))
    })
    observeEvent(input$bins, {
      values$bins <- switch(input$bins, few = 10L, many = 100L)
    })
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      x    <- faithful[, 2]
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = values$bins)
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `req()` in `renderPlot()`. `req()` will tell shiny to render that plot only when `input$bins` is not empty.

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = 
shinyUI(fluidPage(sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(uiOutput("select_bin")),
                                   mainPanel( 
plotOutput("distPlot"))))),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$select_bin <- renderUI({
       selectInput("bins", "Number of bins:", c("few", "many"))
    })
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      req(input$bins)
      x    <- faithful[, 2]
      bins <- switch(input$bins, few = 10L, many = 100L)
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = bins)
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
  })
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Works to omit the warning, but does not allow to show a plot on defaults (using shinydashboard & tabs). Nevertheless +1.

Comment: True, I only know about `selected = T` in `menuItem()`. Cannot find an `active` argument in `? shinydashboard::tabItems`. Do I miss sth?