# Interactively populating array/dataframe for output using R shiny apps

Tags: r, arrays, shiny-reactivity, shinyapps

I am trying to calculate several values based on a user input given in `R shiny app`. Some of the user input is dependent on some other input settings (so the ui is interactive and the sliders ranges depend on another value; that is solved using `renderUI`). So far that works quite well. At the server side I want to calculate results values within an reactive function. The reactive function returns an array/dataframe that is populated by these values that depend on the sliders inputs. The whole script works well and provides the correct output, but I receive some error/warning messages where I don't know how to handle them and why these are raised `(Warning: Error in <-: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`).

Here an example to reproduce the error messages:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test"),

  sidebarLayout(position="left",
                sidebarPanel(selectInput(inputId = "Category", label="Category to choose",
                                         choices = list("A" = "A", "B" = "B"),
                                         selected = "A"),
                             sliderInput(inputId = "sl_1",
                                         label = "Test slider",
                                         value = 3, min = 1, max = 5),
                             uiOutput("slider_test")),
                mainPanel(tableOutput("outtable"),
                          tableOutput("outtext"))))


server <- function(input, output){

  # Dynamic slider ranges depending on turbine type
  slider_param <- reactive({
    par_ls <- list()
    if(input$Category=="A"){
      par_ls$range <- 20
      par_ls$max <- 1000
      }
    if(input$Category=="B"){
      par_ls$range <- 10
      par_ls$max <- 500
      }
    return(par_ls)
  })

  output$slider_test <- renderUI({
    sliderInput(inputId = "sl_2",
                label = "Test slider",
                value = slider_param()$range, min = 1, max = slider_param()$max)})

  ## Calculate parameters on the fly an store in data.frame() for display
  output_reactive <- reactive({
  results_array <- array(data = NA, 
                         dim = c(1,2),
                         dimnames = list(c("row1"),
                                         c("colA","colB")))
  results_array["row1","colA"] <- input$sl_2
  results_array["row1","colB"] <- input$sl_1*input$sl_2
  return(as.data.frame(results_array))
})

  output$outtext <- renderText({input$sl_2})
  output$outtable <- renderTable({
    output_reactive()})

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I assume that this error might be caused by the way how (i.e. in which order) the output value from the slider `input$sl_2` is generated/processed. As `input$sl_2` gets updated after `input$Category` is set (i.e. conditional slider), `input$sl_2` might be empty at the beginning. For example this produces them same kind of error:

```
results_array <- array(data = NA, 
                       dim = c(1,2),
                       dimnames = list(c("row1"),
                                       c("colA","colB")))
sl_2 <- c()
results_array["row1","colA"] <-sl_2
```

**Solution:**
I found a solution by inserting `req()` into `renderTable()`. `req()` will tell shiny to render that table only when input$sl_2 is not empty [https://stackoverflow.com/a/43619933/1035346]

```
  output$outtable <- renderTable({
    req(input$sl_2)
    output_reactive()})
```

Comment: The warning is caused by calculations like `c(1,2) + c(1,2,3)`.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
I found a solution by inserting `req()` into `renderTable()`. `req()` will tell shiny to render that table only when input$sl_2 is not empty [https://stackoverflow.com/a/43619933/1035346]

```
  output$outtable <- renderTable({
    req(input$sl_2)
    output_reactive()})
```